# What is the easiest way to debug and test minifilter driver in visual studio?

Tags: visual-studio, driver, minifilter

I'm working on some sample drivers but it's very annoying to test the code, simply I want to figure out what values are passing in the code of driver.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is supposed to be possible with newer versions of Visual Studio, but I have not had good luck. Windbg is your friend.

I find that the easiest way to debug and test is to run a machine with Hyper-V installed, have a virtual machine that hosts a client OS and on which you install and test your filter driver. Then on the host machine you can run windbg, attach it to a virtual COM port on the VM, and you're up and running.

Since windbg is running on the machine where you are doing dev work, the symbols and source usually just resolve automatically. If you run into problems with that, like you have built a new driver but haven't updated in on the VM and still want to debug, you can set up a build script that keeps a symbol server of recent builds, or you can just force windbg to load the symbols anyway (even though they won't match up perfectly).

In my experience this is FAR easier that getting VS driver debugging to work.